Image-to-directory triaging with hotkeys support
I'm looking for an image triage software, preferably a GUI application that satisfies the following requirements:

the view pane with the current image to triage preview;
the view pane with target directories (preferably with previews and directory name);
the triage action, which is supposed to move the current image to one of the directories, is simply done by pressing a directory-respective shortcut (maybe auto-assigned like Vimium?);
undo shortcut.

In short, I'm looking for a quick way to categorize images by moving them to respective directories using keyboard.
A TUI tool that can render images in image-compatible terminals like Kitty, or render images using ANSI codes (or even sixels) for true-color (or reduced number of colors but probably not less than 256) supporting terminals are also fine (I hope I'd manage to get the images rendered right).
The platform I'm oriented to is Linux. However, if there is any similar software for other platforms, please suggest.
